# Finding a maximal cylinder to be placed in a sphere

Tags: derivatives, volume

Take both volumes, viz.: pi r^2 h to be < 4/3 pi a^3, to distinguish between radii of the 2 figures, let us call the radius of the sphere a

pi is divided out

r^2 h < 4/3 a^3

It is time to take the derivate in order to find the maximal r, but the 4/3 a^3 in case of differentiating on r, is a constant, and is lost in the derivative. With thus all useful info is lost. But I see no way to retain the constant in the derivative. Or is there a cleverer way? thank you

Comment: Care to explain the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is you haven't actually made any link between r,h and a.

I presume a is constant here, and you want the r and h of a cylinder that (a) fits inside the sphere, and (b) has maximal volume. Yes?

Intuitively, the top and bottom of the cylinder will be jammed against the internal walls of the sphere. If you draw a side-on diagram, you'll see a right-angle triangle with sides $r$ and $h/2$, and hypotenuse $a$. So, you get $a^2=r^2 + h^2/4$.

Now, you can either

- rearrange that formula, substitute it into the equation for the cylinder's volume to get a formula involving either $r$ only or $h$ only, then differentiate that to find the $r$ or $h$ that maximises the volume
- differentiate both $V=\pi r^2 h$ and $a^2=r^2+h^2/4$ implicitly, to get two equations for $dV/dh$ and $dr/dh$ (or $dV/dr$ and $dh/dr$). Then set $dV/dh$ (or $dV/dr$) to zero, eliminate the other derivative and one of $h$ and $r$ (using $a^2=r^2+h^2/4$), and you'll have the other of $h$ and $r$.

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you so much. How can choose between dV/dr and dV/dh? how can I know, which vilume is bigger?

Comment: either one will work; whichever you choose, you'll get the same answer.

r is a function of h... or alternatively, h is a function of r. Each one determines the other (once you've fixed a). Then, $dV/dr = (dV/dh)(dh/dr)$ by the chain rule. Or alternatively, $dV/dh = (dV/dr)(dr/dh)$ by the chain rule. So whenever $dV/dr=0$, you must also have $dV/dh=0$, and vice-versa. It doesnt matter which one you choose to solve for $V,h,r,$etc, you'll get tthe same answers either way.